# SQLite Window functions

Tags: sqlite, max, common-table-expression, window-functions, min

This is a simplified ER diagram of my database:

[image: ER diagram]

What I'd like to retrieve is, for each *vendor_item*:

- The *highest* price (excluding the last capture)
- The *lowest* price (excluding the last capture)
- The *current* price (i.e. the last capture)

This is some sample data of the `PRICE_DATA` table to give you an idea:

| vendor_item_id | capture_ts | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 124 | 2022-03-02 09:00:12.851043 | 46.78 |
| 124 | 2022-03-02 14:07:49.423343 | 42.99 |
| 124 | 2022-03-04 08:20:07.636140 | 43.99 |
| 124 | 2022-03-05 08:29:20.421764 | 42.99 |
| 124 | 2022-03-08 08:33:59.043372 | 42.99 |
| 129 | 2022-03-02 08:55:14.401816 | 21.52 |
| 129 | 2022-03-02 14:11:20.544427 | 25.54 |
| 129 | 2022-03-04 08:24:06.976667 | 25.72 |
| 129 | 2022-03-08 08:22:46.734662 | 30.83 |
| 132 | 2022-03-02 09:04:18.144494 | 41.99 |
| 132 | 2022-03-03 08:29:15.981712 | 42.99 |
| 132 | 2022-03-04 08:27:39.327779 | 41.99 |
| 132 | 2022-03-07 08:29:41.236009 | 42.99 |
| 132 | 2022-03-08 08:27:44.318570 | 40.99 |

This is the SQL statement I have so far:

```sql
select distinct vendor_item_id
      ,last_value(price) over win as curr_price
      ,min(price) over win as low_price
      ,max(price) over win as high_price
from price_data
window win as (partition by vendor_item_id 
               order by capture_ts 
               rows between unbounded preceding 
                        and unbounded following);
```

While this gives me more or less what I'm looking for, there are a couple of issues:

- The highest and lowest price take into account *all* records, instead of excluding the most recent capture.
- If I don't add `distinct` to the query, I end up with duplicate records (this is probably my fault, for failing to properly grasp the windowing functionality).

Desired result:

| vendor_item_id | curr_price | low_price | high_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 124 | 42.99 | 42.99 | 46.78 |
| 129 | 30.83 | 21.52 | 25.72 |
| 132 | 40.99 | 41.99 | 42.99 |

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE that returns the max `capture_ts` for each `vendor_item_id` and then get `low_price` and `high_price` with conditional aggregation:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, MAX(capture_ts) OVER (PARTITION BY vendor_item_id) max_capture_ts
  FROM price_data
)
SELECT DISTINCT vendor_item_id,
       FIRST_VALUE(price) OVER (PARTITION BY vendor_item_id ORDER BY capture_ts DESC) curr_price,
       MIN(CASE WHEN capture_ts < max_capture_ts THEN price END) OVER (PARTITION BY vendor_item_id) low_price, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN capture_ts < max_capture_ts THEN price END) OVER (PARTITION BY vendor_item_id) high_price
FROM cte;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2416e07d9f41b1529bca22b9d119850b).

Comment: Thank you for taking the effort to add the demo, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using CTEs and regular aggregate functions to solve the question:

```sql
with v_last_capture as (
    select vendor_item_id
          ,max(capture_ts) last_capture_ts
      from price_data pd
     group by vendor_item_id
)
, v_curr_price as (
    select pd.*
      from price_data pd 
      inner join v_last_capture vc 
            on (pd.vendor_item_id = vc.vendor_item_id and 
                pd.capture_ts = vc.last_capture_ts)
)
, v_other_prices as (
    select vendor_item_id
          ,min(pd.price) as min_price
          ,max(pd.price) as max_price
      from price_data pd
     where id not in (select id from v_curr_price)
     group by vendor_item_id 
)
select vc.id
      ,vc.vendor_item_id 
      ,vc.price as curr_price 
      ,vc.stock
      ,vo.min_price
      ,vo.max_price 
  from v_curr_price vc 
  left join v_other_prices vo on (vc.vendor_item_id = vo.vendor_item_id)
```

Explain plan:

```
QUERY PLAN
|--MATERIALIZE 4
|  |--SCAN TABLE price_data AS pd
|  `--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
|--MATERIALIZE 5
|  |--SCAN TABLE price_data AS pd
|  |--LIST SUBQUERY 6
|  |  |--MATERIALIZE 8
|  |  |  |--SCAN TABLE price_data AS pd
|  |  |  `--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
|  |  |--SCAN SUBQUERY 8 AS vc
|  |  `--SEARCH TABLE price_data AS pd USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (vendor_item_id=? AND capture_ts=?)
|  `--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
|--SCAN TABLE price_data AS pd
|--SEARCH SUBQUERY 4 AS vc USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (vendor_item_id=?)
`--SEARCH SUBQUERY 5 AS vo USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (vendor_item_id=?)
```

The answer of [@forpas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71412524/3165737) works just as well (and the query is more concise). Here's the explain plan for his query:

```
QUERY PLAN
|--CO-ROUTINE 3
|  |--CO-ROUTINE 4
|  |  |--CO-ROUTINE 1
|  |  |  |--CO-ROUTINE 5
|  |  |  |  |--SCAN TABLE price_data
|  |  |  |  `--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
|  |  |  `--SCAN SUBQUERY 5
|  |  |--SCAN SUBQUERY 1
|  |  `--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
|  |--SCAN SUBQUERY 4
|  `--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
|--SCAN SUBQUERY 3
`--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT
```

Comment: For someone unfamiliar with understanding the output of the `QUERY PLAN` could you comment if your Query is faster?  Are there other differences in the two query plans that usefull to be explained?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [window filters](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#the_filter_clause) to remove the last row for your "except the latest capture" requirement

```
select distinct
    p.vendor_item_id
    ,last_value(p.price) over vendor_item as curr_price
    ,min(price) filter (where p.capture_ts < latest.capture_ts) over vendor_item as low_price
    ,max(price) filter (where p.capture_ts < latest.capture_ts) over vendor_item as high_price
from
    price_data p
    inner join (
        select vendor_item_id, max(capture_ts) capture_ts from price_data group by vendor_item_id
    ) latest on latest.vendor_item_id = p.vendor_item_id
window
    vendor_item as (
        partition by p.vendor_item_id
        order by p.capture_ts 
        rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
    );
```

result

```
124 42.99   42.99   46.78
129 30.83   21.52   25.72
132 40.99   41.99   42.99
```

I suppose that `capture_ts` is unique per `vendor_item_id`, otherwise you'd have to create a smarter filter.

Query plan on a naked `price_data` table with no indexes defined:

```
QUERY PLAN
|--CO-ROUTINE 3
|  |--MATERIALIZE 1
|  |  |--SCAN TABLE price_data
|  |  `--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
|  |--SCAN TABLE price_data AS p
|  |--SEARCH SUBQUERY 1 AS latest USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (vendor_item_id=?)
|  `--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
|--SCAN SUBQUERY 3
`--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT
```

when a covering index is defined (`create index ix_price_data on price_data (vendor_item_id, capture_ts, price)`), things get a tiny bit simpler:

```
QUERY PLAN
|--CO-ROUTINE 3
|  |--MATERIALIZE 1
|  |  `--SCAN TABLE price_data USING COVERING INDEX ix_price_data
|  |--SCAN SUBQUERY 1 AS latest
|  |--SEARCH TABLE price_data AS p USING COVERING INDEX ix_price_data (vendor_item_id=?)
|  `--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
|--SCAN SUBQUERY 3
`--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT
```

Since a covering index bumps up the database size (all the data lives as a copy in the index, after all), you could decide that you want to re-create `price_data` as a clustering index, i.e. create the table `WITHOUT ROWID` and mark `vendor_item_id, capture_ts` as the primary key. You can get rid of the then-useless `id` column, too.

This way you would get the same performance as with an explicit index, but without the size bump to the database (in fact the table should get measurably smaller, since the row_id is gone). The query plan stays the same.